# Should there be a "belongs on stackexchange" checkbox in the SO close dialog?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange

From time to time there are proj mgmt questions; really seems that they belong elsewhere.

Is there a friendly relationship to allow that?

Comment: gee I don't know why this is being downvoted.  is it impolite to ask such questions?

Comment: +1 Same question came again today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37423/mention-other-stackexchange-sites-when-question-gets-closed-as-not-programming-re   It's a valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackExchange is conceptually not related to SO at all, it just happens to be made by the same company using the same technology. It's similar to asking for a "Belongs on Yahoo Answers" or "Belongs on Experts Exchange" checkbox.

Project Management questions seem to have no natural place within the StackOverflow Network, so they should just be closed. Comments can then be used to recommend another website, which could be StackExchange, but also many others.

Comment: Agreed, this falls into the category "Not Stack Overflow-related"

Answer (score 2):

The standard close dialog has the 4 most common network migration destinations, plus meta.

However, community moderators can migrate to [any site in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), so flag any questions you feel strongly should be migrated elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Since the belongs-on checkboxes end up migrating the questions, and there are a huge amount of StackExchange sites (some competing), there'd be a logistical problem to figure out where to migrate the question.

That's where the 'belongs-on' tags really show their strength since we could have one for each applicable site.  For example, I had started a 'belongs-on-doctype' tag for those types of questions, but someone who didn't like the 'belongs-on' tags deleted it, throwing out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: Why not just leave a *helpful* comment and vote to close? Flag for mod attention if you want to. But misusing tags is frowned upon by the majority.

Comment: @random, Misusing tags could be construed for the 'belongs-on-superuser' type tags where the option to migrate for that site exists (still debatable), but when there is no migrate option, then I think the 'belongs-on' tags are completely appropriate.  The only reason I can think of not wanting to implement those tags is that there are really a lot of StackExchange sites, and some of them come and go, so the tags will become irrelevant.  Thinking about it though, it'd be kinda cool if you could have certain tags that have links behind them, to take you to the relevant sites.

Comment: I like the idea for belongs-on tags.  Not sure what you mean by "there really are a lot of StackExchange sites".  I am aware only of StackExchange.  Or do you mean "many alternative sites that handle IT-pro type questions" ?   If that's the case, I don't understand why stackexchange is not linked into stackoverflow, esp considering that it uses the same technology.  a prior answer indicated it was run by the same company.  So I don't know why SOFU is a closed cadre, and StackExchange is not allowed in.

Comment: @Cheeso, StackExchange is a commercial product based on the SO model that is used by hundreds of sites, see this list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Comment: __Please don't delete this answer__ just because you disagree with it.  That's what voting is for.